# The coordinate axes are not regularly imbedded in $\mathbb{A}_k^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Exercise 12.1.F of Ravi Vakil's notes asks to prove that the scheme, $X$, which is the union of the coordinate axes in $\mathbb{A}_k^3$ is not regularly imbedded in $\mathbb{A}_k^3$.  The first part of the exercise asks to prove that the ideal cutting out X, $$I:=(xy, yz, xz),$$ is not generated by fewer than 3 elements. Let's assume we've already proved that. **How then do we proceed?**  It is clear that $I$ itself is not generated by a regular sequence, else, by the first part of the exercise, such a sequence has length at least 3, and so the irreducible components of $I$ (which are lines) would have dimension zero.  But in the notes, regularity is defined locally: $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ is a regular imbedding if, for every $p\in X$,  the kernel of $\mathscr{O}_{Y,\pi(p)}\to\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is generated by a regular sequence.  Now I do know that if $\pi$ is regular *at $p$,* then there exists an affine neighborhood $\operatorname{spec} B$ of $\pi(p)$ with $\pi^{-1}(\operatorname{spec} B) = \operatorname{spec} A$ such that the kernel of $B\to A$ is generated by a regular sequence.  But I don't know whether if $Y$ ($= \operatorname{spec} k[x,y,z]$) is affine, that I can "glue" all those regular sequences together to get a regular sequence for $I$.

Comment: Please use `$\operatorname{spec}$` to format $\operatorname{spec}$: it looks better and produces better spacing. I've made the change in your post this time.

Comment: @KReiser I will. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting ahead of yourself with the comments on gluing: in general, it may not be the case that a regular immersion of affine schemes must be globally cut out by a regular sequence (indeed, for codimension-one regular immersions, this is exactly saying that there are effective Cartier divisors which are not the divisor of a rational function). Instead, in this case it's better to find a point so that that the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\pi(p)}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is not generated by a regular sequence. Since the origin is the only singular point, it would make sense to look there, where the map $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\pi(p)}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is given by $k[x,y,z]_{(x,y,z)}\to (k[x,y,z]/I)_{(x,y,z)}$, where the kernel is $I_{(x,y,z)}$.

But $I_{(x,y,z)}$ cannot be generated by two elements for the same reason that $I$ cannot be generated by two elements. To avoid potentially spoiling the first part of the problem, I'll put the explanation under some spoiler text:

> If $I_{(x,y,z)}$ could be generated by two elements, then $\dim I_{(x,y,z)}/(x,y,z)_{(x,y,z)}I_{(x,y,z)}\leq 2$. But $I_{(x,y,z)}/(x,y,z)_{(x,y,z)}I_{(x,y,z)}$ is exactly $(I/(x,y,z)I)_{(x,y,z)}$ since localization is exact, and because every element of $k[x,y,z]\setminus (x,y,z)$ already acts invertibly on $I/(x,y,z)I$, we have that $I_{(x,y,z)}/(x,y,z)_{(x,y,z)}I_{(x,y,z)}\cong I/(x,y,z)I$, and the dimension of $I/(x,y,z)I$ can be seen to be three by looking at the classes $xy$, $xz$, and $yz$ and noticing that they're $k$-linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you!  Ravi's hint for the first part is "work modulo a power of (x,y,z)."  I wonder if he meant rather modulo $I(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @famousmortimer That should also work - the key insight from the spoiler block about the computation being the same for the whole coordinate ring and the local ring at the origin will also apply there.

Comment: Thanks again. All is clear.  Though I am still puzzled because the exercise is situated in a section about tangent spaces, and it is preceded by similar exercises showing that ideals cannot be generated by fewer elements.  Solutions to those exercises proceed by computing the dimension of the tangent space (usually at the origin) to the closed subscheme of the ideal and concluding that, with fewer generators, the subscheme could not cut-away the required number of dimensions from the ambient tangent space.  I can't help but wonder if there is a similar interpretation here that I'm missing.

Comment: The construction $(I/(x,y,z)I)_{(x,y,z)}$ looks *sort-of* like a cotangent space, but not exactly

Comment: Took me a bit to think of the solution Vakil is probably going for, but try looking at $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ for $n=1,2$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of the coordinate axes at the origin and compare with what you have for the whole space. When $n=1$, you'll see that the dimensions are equal, so all generators of $I$ have to be in $\mathfrak{m}^2$, and then when $n=2$ you'll see that the dimension is cut down by 3, which can't happen from 2 generators in $\mathfrak{m}^2$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you again!